# Parse String Array of regex values within PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, regex, string

The combination of the way I'm working with this is complex and I can't find any reference on how to accomplish it.

I'm allowing the user to store a representation of an array of regex values in the database (MySql) like so:

```
'["/^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/i", "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/i"]'
```

Now in my PHP code I read it into a variable `$val` and it looks like this:

```
'["/^\\d{5}([\\-]?\\d{4})?$/i", "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\\ {0,1}(\\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\\d)$/i"]'
```

and trying to leverage JSON to decode it into an actual array:

```
$val = '{"unq":'.$val.'}';
$obs = json_decode($val);
return $obs->unq;
```

Problem is, I get `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...` on `$obs->unq;`

I'm guessing this has to do with the way the regex is being stored, but I'm not certain. Too many wasted hours on this, thanks for your help.

Comment: your issue is "NOT" clear. first read the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn to read your errors... why would you get an object property from an array given value ???

Comment: I didn't mean to accidentally up-vote your comment. You didn't read my question. Please read it fully before down-voting it. As you can see with the line `$val - '{"unq":'.$val.'}';`, I convert this to an object so that I can utilize json to convert to object form. I'm hoping to retrieve the array by `$obj->unq;` What is wrong with this???

Comment: answered ! i've just claimed a little bit more explaination about origin of your purpose (the need of string regex, the way you are using to do it... etc). i upvote your comment to equilibrate until a can edit your post to revert the vote ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem's your parser (mysqli_real_escaped_string or something else) does not escape any of structural characters expected in a json string (except unicode chars i guess)

As you can read in the [JSON RFC about strings escaping slashes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#section-7) (forward or backward) should be escaped !

> "The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C
> family of programming languages"

Then, you can use addcslashes to escape it:

```
$reg = addcslashes($reg, chr(0x5c)); // hex notation, beware of '\\'
$out = '{"unq":'.$reg.'}';
$out = json_decode($out);
```

## Hint

You should use native debug functions like var_dump and json error handler to ensure where error occur from:

```
var_dump(json_last_error_msg(), $out);
return $out->unq;
```

in error way:

```
string(12) "Syntax error"
NULL
```

solved:

```
string(8) "No error"
object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
  ["unq"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(23) "/^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/i"
    [1]=>
    string(86) "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/i"
  }
}
```

## Storage

I dont know about your purpose, but there is another way to help on this king of storage.
You can also serialize a true array of regex

```
// before saving
$patterns = serialize
([
    "/^\d{5}([\-]?\d{4})?$/i",
    "/^([ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVXY]\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ])\ {0,1}(\d[ABCEGHJKLMNPRSTVWXYZ]\d)$/i",
]);

// usage out of mysql, unserialize do the tricks
return $patterns = unserialize($sqlressource["patterns"]);
```